# tengo un error que dice status 400, ¿que debo hacer?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

tengo una aplicacion hecha con React/Redux y Firebase y pueas a la hora de crear un usuario si creo uno y este se loggea con google luego no puede loguearse normalmente y si creo uno y el primer boton que aprieta es sign-in normal sin google se loguea pero luego no puede loguearse con google.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
sign-in component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import FormInput from '../form-input/form-input.component';
import CustomButton from '../custom-button/custom-button.component';

import {
  googleSignInStart,
  emailSignInStart
} from '../../redux/user/user.actions';
import "./sign-in.styles.scss";

const SignIn = ({ emailSignInStart, googleSignInStart }) => {
  const [userCredentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const { email, password } = userCredentials;

  const handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    emailSignInStart(email, password);
  };

  const handleChange = event => {
    const { value, name } = event.target;

    setCredentials({ ...userCredentials, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="sign-in">
      <h2>I already have an account</h2>
      <span>Sign in with your email and password</span>
  
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormInput
          name="email"
          type="email"
          value={email}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          label="email"
          required
        />
        <FormInput
          name="password"
          type="password"
          value={password}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          label="password"
          required
        />
        <div className="buttons">
          <CustomButton type="submit">Sign In</CustomButton>
          <CustomButton
            type="button"
            onClick={googleSignInStart}
            isGoogleSignIn
          >
            Sign In with Google
          </CustomButton>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  googleSignInStart: () => dispatch(googleSignInStart()),
  emailSignInStart: (email, password) =>
    dispatch(emailSignInStart({ email, password }))
});

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SignIn);
```

firebase.utils.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

const config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBWrW38eq1eSNUUhs_T7raPons6_8OfxKI",
  authDomain: "crown-db-4243b.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://crown-db-4243b.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "crown-db-4243b",
  storageBucket: "crown-db-4243b.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "500798355673",
  appId: "1:500798355673:web:fc08cf5afdceb35a79a6c8",
  measurementId: "G-LNFRDT7XV6"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
  if (!userAuth) return;

  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${userAuth.uid}`);

  const snapShot = await userRef.get();

  if (!snapShot.exists) {
    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const createdAt = new Date();
    try {
      await userRef.set({
        displayName,
        email,
        createdAt,
        ...additionalData
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error creating user', error.message);
    }
  }

  return userRef;
};

export const addCollectionAndDocuments = async (
  collectionKey,
  objectsToAdd
) => {
  const collectionRef = firestore.collection(collectionKey);

  const batch = firestore.batch();
  objectsToAdd.forEach(obj => {
    const newDocRef = collectionRef.doc();
    batch.set(newDocRef, obj);
  });

  return await batch.commit();
};

export const convertCollectionsSnapshotToMap = collections => {
  const transformedCollection = collections.docs.map(doc => {
    const { title, items } = doc.data();

    return {
      routeName: encodeURI(title.toLowerCase()),
      id: doc.id,
      title,
      items
    };
  });

  return transformedCollection.reduce((accumulator, collection) => {
    accumulator[collection.title.toLowerCase()] = collection;
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
};

export const getCurrentUser = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
      unsubscribe();
      resolve(userAuth);
    }, reject);
  });
};

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

export const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
googleProvider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider);

export default firebase;
```

Comment: El error 400 significa que la petición está mal hecha, puedes revisar la url con los parámetros con Postman.

Comment: pero estoy usando firebase, no hice yo misma el backend solo lo estoy estirando de ahi.